# Opening fragment on clicking on Notification

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, push-notification

I have one `SplashActivity` and one `MainActivity` and all the fragments are associated with `MainActivity`. Now whenever I recive `Notification` from server I want to open one specific fragment. I am opening this like

```
final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(getIntent().getAction().equals("OpenNotificationFragment")) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_main_container, new NotificationFragment()).addToBackStack(PastOrderFragment.TAG)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

but during my splash image is loading it is throwing `NullPointerException`, should I call this method in `SplashActivity` or edit some of my code.

Comment: Where is that above code?

Comment: I am using this code in mainActivity's onCreate method()

Comment: is it your getIntent().getAction() becoming null ?? while raising intent from your notification you must have done setAction but you would not have set any action while sending intent to main activity from SplashActivity ??